# Protractor locator ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, protractor, functional-testing

I had this :

```
<span>{{ $ctrl.title }}</span>
```

And I was testing it with this:

```
element(by.binding('$ctrl.title'))
```

And it was working.

After that I needed the title not to be a plain text but a html instead because I wanted to add some h1, h2 tags also in that text so I've updated my html like this:

```
<span ng-bind-html="$ctrl.buildHtmlContent()"></span>

buildHtmlContent() {
    return this.$sce.trustAsHtml(this.title);
}
```

But the testing fails, I need to replace the element locator but I don't know with what. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simpler than I though, I just had to replace this:

```
element(by.binding('$ctrl.title'))
```

with this:

```
element(by.binding('$ctrl.buildHtmlContent()'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector:

```
by.css('div[ng-bind-html="$ctrl.buildHtmlContent()"]')
```

Or you can add additional attribute so test depends less on implementation:

```
<span ng-bind-html="$ctrl.buildHtmlContent()" e2e-title></span>
by.css('div[e2e-title]')
```